# Call a Method of Subclass in Java without Downcasting

Tags: java, inheritance

I have superclass Address and some subclasses extend it.These subclasses have some other field additional to superclass.I choose object type in switch-case structure and when select one of the subclasses,I want to set the subclass spesific field.(For example `endPointReference` for `AddresWS` subclass)

Because reference variable is type of superclass,I need to downcast it to call subclass setter method.I think downcasting is bad solution and point to bad design.But I dont know how to solve it.I need to your suggestions.

```
public abstract class Address {

    private String addressOid = "";
    private String tcknVkn = "";
    private String alias = "";
    private int addressType = -1;
    private String aliasType;
    
    //getters and setters
}

public class AddressWS extends Address{
    private String endPointReference = "";

    public AddressWS(String oid,String tcknVkn,String alias,int addressType,String aliasType){
        this.setAddressOid(oid);
        this.setTcknVkn(tcknVkn);
        this.setAlias(alias);
        this.setAddressType(addressType);
        this.setAliasType(aliasType);
    }
    //getter and setter
}

public Address findAddress(String tcknVkn, String alias) throws EFaturaException {
            
            Address address =null;
            
            int addressType=(Integer) adrTypeAndOrgoidAndTurList.get(0)[0];
            String oid=(String) adrTypeAndOrgoidAndTurList.get(0)[1];
            String aliasType=(String) adrTypeAndOrgoidAndTurList.get(0)[2];

            switch (addressType) {
                case Constants.ADDRESSTYPEWS:
                    address = new AddressWS(oid,tcknVkn,alias,addressType,aliasType);
                    address.setEndPointReference(epr); //COMPILE ERROR,NEED TO DOWNCASTING
                    break;
              //other cases
                
            }
            return address;
        }
```

Comment: Best way, you don't. Remember, not every address is an AddressWS. For all you know, somebody creates other subclasses. Even if you don't, the compiler has no means of knowing that.

Comment: It seems like you are storing heterogeneous data in an array. Create a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: declare a local variable of the right type, and assign this back to the supertype variable:

```
AddressWS addressWs = new AddressWS(oid,tcknVkn,alias,addressType,aliasType);
address = addressWs;
// Do specific stuff to addressWs.
```

Comment: Is this best solution ? Don't I need to change my design?

Comment: Do you want to change your design? Of course you can if you want, but that seems somewhat more extreme than declaring another variable.

Comment: But when I assign addressWS to address variable,I dont do spesific stuff to addressWs.

Comment: Infact I need a review for is this design problematic or not.

Comment: Assigning `addressWs` to `address` doesn't do anything other than make them refer to the same object. Anything you do to `addressWs` is visible in `address` (and vice versa).

Comment: I can't review your design. A design is a plan to achieve a particular goal by balancing competing requirements: I know neither your goal nor your requirements.